# I want to push my Flutter code to Github, but why are pull requests in Github only for public repositories?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I'm pushing my Flutter code to [Github](https://github.com). I installed an extension called "[GitHub Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github)". When I installed it, it would have a new Github icon in the activity bar, as shown in the image below:

[image]

When I click on this icon, it will display the following image:

[image]

When I move the mouse over the word "PULL REQUESTS", it shows a create pull request button. When I click on it, it displays something like the image below:

[image]

When I click on the create button, it pops up a dialog asking me if I'm sure. I clicked on the publish button and it shows as shown in the image below:

[image]

> You don't have permissions to push to 'mycar98765/project' on GitHub.
> Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead?

I think, it pops up this warning because my repository is private and not public. If I am, why pull requests in Github only work for public repositories and how to fix this? If I'm not, why is it popping up this warning and how to fix it?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The warning is almost unreadable. You might want to consider going the extra step and post it as text instead of a screenshoot.

Comment: It looks like you don't have the permission to push to the repository. Are you sure you configured the correct credentials, i.e. ssh-key?

Comment: @SebDieBln what is that? How to do it?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account You can use an ssh key instead of username/password for better security.

Comment: @SebDieBln can you answer this question and share the whole solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your Github credential and set it again.

Windows

1. Open Credential Manager on Windows search.
2. Select Windows Credentials.
3. Then under Generic Credentials remove Github credentials.
4. Then push your commit again, and follow the steps that Github will provide.

Mac

1. Open Keychain Access from Launchpad.

[image]

[image]

2. Then search "Github".
3. Delete the 2 values that appears.
4. Then push your commit again, and follow the steps that Github will provide.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm using a MacBook instead of Windows

Comment: @MyCar ill edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for your edited answer :)

Comment: What is "Keychain Access"? Can you screenshot how to open "Keychain Access"?

Comment: Beside your "Finder" open the "Launchpad"  the one with spaceship icon. Then search keychain and Keychain Access will show.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, this is [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpfRv.png)

Comment: Oh you say this. I got it now

Comment: I follow all your solutions but same problem